# ChoiceType with choices from a list of objects returns an object instead of string

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Is there a specific option to force the `ChoiceType` field to return as a string?

Well, actually, the submit does return a string, but somehow the handleRequest-function converts it back into an object , which it shouldn't! ("Expected string, got object" -error)

To solve this quickly, I made a traditional list (key/label => value) looping through the objects and getting the label and value from each object, but that seems so unlike Symfony.

This does not work with a countryList made out of country entities:

```
$builder->add('somefield',ChoiceType::class,[
    'choices' => $countryList,
    'expanded' => false,
    'choice_value' => function (?Country $entity) {
        return $entity ? $entity->getCode() : '';
    },
    'choice_label' => function (?Country $entity) {
        return $entity ? $entity->getName() : '';
    },
]);
```

(I know that you could have mapped the column `somefield` to an object, but now it just expects a string.)

Comment: What exactly is throwing the Expected string, got object error?

Comment: It is the controller when it arrives at handleRequest($request). When I change the countryList to hash it works.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks to be performing as expected. I can understand that you might think that Symfony would shun the non-object key-value array as the argument for `choices` but in this case I think it's logical that if you provided it with an array of objects, tell it how to get the object value and label, then it *should* return one of those objects you provided it with.

If you want it to return a string, then I would go with the approach you've already used of providing a hash of [`code` => `name`] for your Country objects.

Alternatively you could leave your code as it is and get the string value for `somefield` with `$form->getData()['somefield']->getName();` or maybe I'm misinterpreting your question and you're getting an exception before reaching this stage.